# Error while calling an API with the AWS generated SDK for iOS, even though the user is logged in

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

In my AWS project, I've created webservices using API Gateway and Lambda.

I use AWSMobileClient for iOS to allow users to sign in / sign out using Cognito, and the API Gateway generated SDK for iOS (Swift) to be able to call APIs from that iOS app.

Here is how i manage Cognito in my iOS app:

1. First, initialize:

```swift
AWSMobileClient.default().initialize { (userState: UserState?, error: Error?) in
    if (userState != nil)
    {
        print("AWSMobileClient initialize OK : \(userState.debugDescription)")
    }
    if (error != nil)
    {
        print("AWSMobileClient initialize error : \(String(describing: error))")
    }
}
```

I got:

```
"AWSMobileClient initialize OK : Optional(AWSMobileClient.UserState.signedOut)"
```

2. Then, sign in:

```swift
AWSMobileClient.default().signIn(
    username: "test@mail.com ",
    password: "abcd1234") { (signInResult: SignInResult?, error: Error?) in

    if (signInResult != nil)
    {
        if (signInResult!.signInState == SignInState.signedIn)
        {
            print("AWSMobileClient sign in OK")
        }
        else
        {
            print("AWSMobileClient sign in error")
        }
    }
    if (error != nil)
    {
        print("AWSMobileClient sign in error \(String(describing: error))")
    }
}
```

I got:

```
"AWSMobileClient sign in OK"
```

3. Now I want to call an API, which requires the user to be logged in:

```swift
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(
    regionType: AWSRegionType.EUCentral1,
    identityPoolId: "eu-central-1:1234abcd-12ab-1234-1234-123456abcdef")
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(
    region: AWSRegionType.EUCentral1,
    credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
AWSServiceManager.default()?.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

let myTestModel: MyTestModel = MyTestModel()
myTestModel.email = "test@mail.com "
myTestModel.newEmail = "test2@mail.com "
let client = MyMobileClient.default()
client
    .signedInModifyInformationsAccountPost(contentType: "application/json", body: myTestModel)
    .continueWith { (awsTask: AWSTask<Empty>) -> Any? in
        if let awsError = awsTask.error as NSError? 
        {
            print("Error: \(awsError.userInfo)")
        }
        if let awsResult = awsTask.result
        {
            print("Success: \(awsResult)"
        }
        return nil
    }
```

But here, I got the following error:

```
Message = "User: arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/wzj-dev-eu-central-1-identity-pool-non-authenticated/CognitoIdentityCredentials
is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource:
arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:********1234:12345abcde/dev/POST/authenticated/modify-informations-account"
```

And I really don't understand that message, since the user is logged in, and I got the confirmation right before calling that API that the user is properly logged in by checking with: `AWSMobileClient.default().currentUserStatus` (which is: `signedIn`). However, the IAM role that you can see in the error is..... the unauthenticated role!

Even more surprisingly, if I quit my app, without signing out the user, and do it all over again, now it works, I can call the same API without any error.

**EDIT:**

*That problem occurs only if I call another API **BEFORE** calling `modify-informations-account`. That other API can be called by both an authenticated and an unauthenticated user. If I don't call that other API, everything works fine.*

So what did I do wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Could be just some cache. When in doubt if user's IAM policy is "enough" or not, you could try to provide for that user full access to the service(s) and try again same call, if it worked, it means your policies where not enough and now you have to find what policy exactly the user need. But in your case, if after refresh it just worked, could be cache in some layer of your network request.

Comment: @LukasLiesis OK, but which cache?

Comment: @mattech Could be even ISP on network layer, I have no way to tell. When in doubt, i usually use fresh incognito session and change my internet to run over proxy service, to make sure to avoid any cache from my side, aka browser, network, ISP etc. till requests hits 1st service. If still seems like cache issue, go through pipe of services to handle the request - DNS, CDNs, other services, but seems like in this case you don't have these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so it was very simple:

unlike what it is said in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk-ios-swift.html), instead of:

```swift
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(
    regionType: AWSRegionType.EUCentral1,
    identityPoolId: "eu-central-1:1234abcd-12ab-1234-1234-123456abcdef")
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(
    region: AWSRegionType.EUCentral1,
    credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
AWSServiceManager.default()?.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

replace it by:

```swift
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(
    region: AWSRegionType.EUCentral1,
    credentialsProvider: AWSMobileClient.default())
AWSServiceManager.default()?.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```